# Box2D stopping a dynamic body from moving after collision

Tags: java

I am trying to re-create Pong using LibGDX and Box2D. I have 2 problems, if I fix one it creates another.

My paddles are currently set to Kinematic and are controlled using the up/down keys via a controller class. This works just fine and I can happily play back and forth.

Problem being, my walls are static bodies and my paddles just travel right through them.

Now I can fix this by simple changing the paddle body to a dynamic one, this stops the paddles from going through the walls but then when my ball strikes off a paddle, it goes flying off the X axis and off the screen.

I have tried adding an update method in my controller class as follows:

```
public void update(float delta){
    paddleBodyPosY = paddleBody.getPosition().x;
    paddleBodyPosY = paddleBody.getPosition().y;
    System.out.println(paddleBodyPosY);

}
```

The console reports the paddle position being updated every frame, from top to bottom of screen.

So I went back to my GameScreen class and tried all sorts of code in the Render() method like so:

```
    if(playerOnePaddle.paddleBodyPosY < 0){
        playerOnePaddle.paddleBody.getPosition().y = 0;
        System.out.println("resetting paddle");
    }
```

I have tried LOADS of variations, I can easily break movement by calling `paddleBody.setLinearVelocity(0,0)` but then it gets stuck like this and it's not movable anymore. Obviously the problem must lie with the fact that I can't set a position using a getter lol.

Any ideas? If you need more snippets ask, I didn't want to overload the question with 100 lines of code you don't need to see :S.

The paddle creation method:

```
public void createPaddle(World world, float x, float y){
        //Define a body for the paddle
        BodyDef paddleBodyDef = new BodyDef();
        paddleBodyDef.type = BodyType.KinematicBody;
        paddleBodyDef.position.set(x, y);

        //Define a shape for the paddle
        PolygonShape paddleShape = new PolygonShape();
        paddleShape.setAsBox(paddleWidth, paddleHeight);

        //Define a fixture for the paddle
        FixtureDef paddleFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        paddleFixtureDef.shape = paddleShape;
        paddleFixtureDef.density = 0;

        //Ensures ball bounces off paddle
        //Consistently without losing velocity
        paddleFixtureDef.restitution = 1.005f;

        //Create the paddles
        paddleBody = world.createBody(paddleBodyDef);
        paddleFixture = paddleBody.createFixture(paddleFixtureDef);

        paddleShape.dispose();      

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried restricting the positions of the paddles instead of relying on physics here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, or rather can't visualize what you mean on code. Further explain?

Comment: Kind of like this part of your question: `if(playerOnePaddle.paddleBodyPosY < 0){
        playerOnePaddle.paddleBody.getPosition().y = 0;
        System.out.println("resetting paddle");
    }` What was wrong with that?

Comment: Literally does nothing, the statement is executing because the console is spamming "resetting paddle" when I go to negative coordinates, but the paddle does not get forced back to 0 like it should

Comment: Show the physical properties that you have applied in your physical body plus have restricting boundaries of your box2d world will also help you.

Comment: updated op with the paddle properties, I never knew you could set boundaries for the box2d world, however that might not work as I am leaving a space at the top for drawing a score. I suppose I could work around that...if I knew how, to google!

Comment: Ok right I can't figure this out at all lol, I have changed my world a bit to be completely surrounded by static bodies to keep the ball in for now, so the issue I have currently is that kinetmatic bodies don't get stopped by static bodies, any ideas what I can do?

Comment: @Gibbo did you figure out how to make kinetmatic bodies to get stopped by static bodies

Answer (score 1):

Heh, so what I did was.

Set my paddles to dynamic, then set there mass to a stupidly high number so that the a ball would not move them on the x axis, well not enough for the human eye to see at least.

Seems like a cheap fix, if anyone has anything better...that would be great lol